# Wie spricht man von der deutschen Sprache?

Tags: word-choice

Es klingt fast wie eine Metafrage, aber wie spricht man eigentlich von der deutschen Sprache (oder von einer anderen)?  Sagt man

> eher *die Schönheit des Deutschen* 
>   oder
>   *die Schönheit vom Deutschen* ?

(Ja, ich weiss, man kann *die Schönheit der deutschen Sprache* sagen aber das ist ein Ausweichen!)

Ähnlich frage ich mich: heisst es

> *ins Deutsche übersetzen* oder *auf Deutsch übersetzen* ?

Und soll ich

> *im Deutschen habe ich Schwierigkeiten* sagen oder *auf Deutsch habe ich Schwierigkeiten* ?

Comment: *Die Schönheit vom Deutsch* ;p

Comment: Dank den Antworten, Kommentaren und Samuels Link habe ich mir folgende Faustregel gebastelt: entweder ungebeugt *Deutsch* für die vier Fälle oder *das Deutsche*, gebeugt nach der üblichen Regel für Adjektive nach bestimmtem Artikel. Dies war meine erste Frage hier und ich bin schon unheimlich begeistert: Danke, meine neuen Freunde!

Comment: "Die Schöhnheit der deutschen Sprache" ist kein Ausweichen, sondern die einzig unmissverständliche Formulierung.  Und es klingt auch am besten.  So schön poetisch, wie Deutsch eben klingen kann.  Die erwähnte Missverständlichkeit?  Siehe mein Kommentar unter der akzeptierten Antwort.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Richtig ist die erste Variante](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Deutsch)

Wichtig ist, dass man es nur mit **bestimmtem** Artikel verwenden darf, oder ganz ohne Artikel.
(Das Deutsche ist eine schöne Sprache; Deutsch ist die Sprache der Dichter und Poeten).
Nun ist es so, dass sich hinter dem Wort "vom" eigentlich "von dem" versteckt, und "dem" wiederum ist das gebeugte "der", bestimmter Artikel im 3. Fall.

Kontrollieren kann man die richtige Anwendung, indem man den gesuchten Teil ("vom Deutschen") durch das Fragewort "Wem" ersetzt und den Satz zu einer Frage umformt:

> Wem seine Schönheit?

Hier nun wird klar, dass es sich um keinen sauberen deutschen Satz handelt. Die Frage muss heißen:

> Wessen Schönheit?

Wessen verlangt den 2. Fall (Genitiv), daraus ergibt sich, dass *Die Schönheit des Deutschen* die richtige Form ist.
Die Ersetzung des Genitivs durch den Dativ ist ein bereits lang laufender Prozess, der vor allem in vielen Dialekten schon weit fortgeschritten ist. Dennoch gibt es wie in diesem Fall sehr viele Wendungen, die nicht mit dem Dativ bestreitbar sind.

> [1] Der Text ist auf Deutsch geschrieben.
>   [1] Der Text ist in gutem/schlechtem Deutsch geschrieben.

Aus den Beispielen schließe ich, dass man *ins Deutsche übersetzt* (es wird wie ein Adjektiv gebraucht) und *auf Deutsch schreibt* (Substantiv).

Die letzte Frage, und wohl die schönste von allen ist

> Mit Deutsch habe ich (meine) Schwierigkeiten

wohl am elegantesten beantwortet.

Comment: "Nominativ," wirklich? Sollte das nicht *Nomen* oder *Substantiv* sein?

Comment: Vielen Dank, ich war zu faul zum googeln ... fast schon lächerlich :D

Comment: Ich verstehe Ihren Einwand gegen *vom Deutschen* nicht: *vom* ist doch eine Verschmelzung der Wörter *von* und *dem*, und Sie behaupten selbst, dass man *Deutsch*  mit Artikel verwenden darf. Empfinden Sie zum Beispiel folgenden Satz als falsch:  *Vom Deutschen kann man behaupten, dass es nicht so leicht ist* ? Wie dem auch sei, ich finde Ihre Charakterisierung der Variante *vom Deutschen*  als "grausam" ein wenig... eigenartig!

Comment: Es hat damit zu tun, daß viele, besonders Jugendliche, oft Dativ, anstelle des richtigen und stillistisch höher liegenden Genitivs benutzen. z.B.: Das ist dem Vater sein Auto. STATT: Das ist das Auto meines Vaters. Scherzhaft sagt man: Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod. Leider du selber bist ein Beweis dieser negativen Tendenz, den Genitiv abzuschaffen. 

"Vom Deutschen" finde ich falsch, es sollte "Über Deutsch" heißen.

Comment: @Georges Im Internet ist es üblich sich mit Du anzusprechen, und ich biete dir das auch gerne an :) Dein Einwand ist sehr berechtigt, das ging mir kurz vor dem Einschlafen ebenfalls durch den Kopf. Also zur Ergänzung: Es ist möglich Deutsch mit dem zu kombinieren, nur ist der Dativ der falsche Fall. Die Schönheit verlangt eindeutig den Genitiv.

Comment: hab auch das grausam rausgetan. Ich bin ein leidenschaftlicher Verteidiger des Genitivs, aber du hast Recht, es ist zu subjektiv.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärungen, Samuel. Ich nehme Dein Angebot mit Vergnügen an, und bin hocherfreut schon nach nur 24 Stunden auf dieser Site einen sympathischen und kompetenten Benutzer gefunden zu haben!

Comment: Das freut mich :) Ich denke für mich hat sich auch spätestens jetzt die Beta-Teilnahme schon ausgezahlt ;)

Comment: @burbuja: Ich bin nun gewiss nicht scheu, mich des Genitivs zu bedienen -- doch kann er allein nicht der Weisheit letzter Schluss sein. Meines Erachtens muss man die Aussage, der Genitiv sei "stilistisch höher liegend", des Sprachpositivismus verdächtigen -- dieses Eindrucks kann ich mich nicht erwehren. 

Denn auch dem Dativ gebührt Anerkennung -- steht ihm doch in der gehobenen Sprache ein ebenso hoher Platz zu wie dem Genitiv. Gäben wir dem einen oder anderen den Vorzug, würde uns das nur zum Nachteil gereichen.Darum: Huldigt dem Dativ, und freut Euch des Genitivs!

Comment: @Martin: ich würde ja "Huldigt dem Genitiv, und freut Euch des Dativs" bevorzugen :D

Comment: "Die Schönheit des Deutschen!"  Ach, der Deutsche ist also schön?  *im Spiegel ankuck*  Ich weiss nicht...

Comment: Dezent gemein eine Verkürzung umzumodeln :D Der gemeinte Satz war: Die Schönheit der deutschen Sprache (ja, auch hier haben wir Genitiv) - und natürlich, die deutsche Sprache ist schön ;), und weil wir schon dabei sind, ein bisschen mehr Sprachpositivismus: "Huldigt dem Genitiv, erfreuet Euch des Dativs" :D

Comment: @Jürgen: Ja, so ist es viel schöner... und so leicht rebellisch. ;)

Answer (score 5):

richtig: Schönheit des Deutschen / der deutschen Sprache / des Deutschen

Dativ anstelle des Genitivs benutzen nur Leute mit einer niedrigeren Bildung

Ins Deutsche übersetzen, aber auf Deutsch sagen.

Comment: @Cerberus, stimmt es handelt sich um Akkusativ, nicht um Nominativ, wie Samuel geschrieben hat. Wahrscheinlich hat er eben, wie du richtig vorschlägst, Substantiv gemeint.

Comment: Ja, er hat es schon geändert. Verzeihung bitte wegen meines schlechten Deutsches; ich schreibe nicht oft auf Deutsch. Weißt du eigentlich, daß ich nur dann von deinem Kommentar einen Bericht empfange, wann du meinen Name genau so schreibst, wie hier geschrieben? Ferner schreibt man auf dieser Website gewönlich den Kommentar unter demjenige, auf das man reagiert.

Comment: @Cerberus, ich weiß nicht warum, aber ich konnte es einfach nicht darunter schreiben, weil diese Möglichkeit für mich nicht vorhanden war. Dein Deutsch ist ganz gut. Nur ein Fehler:
wegen meines schlechten Deutsches --> Deutschen oder Deutsch. Wann du meinen Name genau so schreibst --> wenn ... Namen;
Verzeihung bitte ---> Verzeih / Entschuldige.

Comment: Das liegt an der Reputation, es dauert ein bisschen bis man die rRechte hat a) Fragen zu kommentieren und b) Antworten zu kommentieren. Eigene Antworten kann man jedoch von Anfang an kommentieren ;)

Comment: Sprachgebrauch hat in erster Linie mit kultureller Prägung zu tun. Die Unterstellung eines direkten Zusammenhangs mit dem Bildungsniveau finde ich etwas weit hergeholt.